# sql sorting by subgroup sum data

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by

How sort this

```
a 1 15
a 2 3
a 3 34
b 1 55
b 2 44
b 3 8
```

to (by third column sum):

```
b 1 55
b 2 44
b 3 8
a 1 15
a 2 3
a 3 34
```

since (55+44+8) > (15+3+34)

Comment: School work, or work task, or just for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server/Oracle/Postgresql you could use windowed `SUM`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY SUM(col3) OVER(PARTITION BY col) DESC, col2
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/450220)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╗
║ col ║ col2 ║ col3 ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╣
║ b   ║    1 ║   55 ║
║ b   ║    2 ║   44 ║
║ b   ║    3 ║    8 ║
║ a   ║    1 ║   15 ║
║ a   ║    2 ║    3 ║
║ a   ║    3 ║   34 ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ANSI standard window functions.  I prefer to use a subquery although this is not strictly necessary:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (select t.*, sum(col3) over (partition by col1) as sumcol3
      from t
     ) t
order by sumcol3 desc, col3 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

...and an example how to do it without windowing functions, in for example MySQL (but also in just about any other standard SQL version)

```
SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3
FROM myTable m
JOIN (
  SELECT col1, SUM(col3) groupsum FROM myTable GROUP BY col1
) z ON m.col1 = z.col1
ORDER BY z.groupsum DESC, col2;
```

Basically, calculate the group sum in a subquery and join/order the results by the group's sum descending.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf8eb/1).